# Twilio Video Startup

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

I am fairly new to React and am trying to run an example to get started with understanding how Twilio interfaces with React/Node. I am currently using the repo https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js, and am trying to run the `test > framework > twilio-video-react`, but when I `npm install` then `npm start`, the server starts, but throws the error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/App.js 
Module not found: Can't resolve 'twilio-video'
```

I did `npm install twilio-video`, but still throwing error. What am I missing here? Can anyone else get this example started? I want a base example with Twilio Video working with React so I can learn from there, any other resources would help, thanks!

I tried these two examples as well, but they are outdated:

- https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/03/video-chat-react.html
- https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/03/building-a-react-powered-video-chat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, got an example up and running with a little fudging.

I followed this example: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/03/video-chat-react.html
But there were a few old libraries that were causing errors.

Posted a working version on my [Github linked here](https://github.com/douglasrcjames/twilio-video-react).

Comment: This is cool, thanks for sticking with it. Hope you learned what you need and can use Twilio Video in a full app when you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the positivity mate, I’ll need it!!